# Why is a ruby dependency, rake, required if it is already included with ruby?

Tags: ruby

While trying to install Capistrano, I got an error message that rake was not available. since rake is included with ruby, what do I need to do?

Comment: If your question "why" or "what"?

Comment: You can help us if you edit your question to add more information. Can you copy/paste the exact command you are running, and the error message? Can you copy/paste the exact output of these commands: "command -v ruby", "command -v rake", "ruby -v", "rake --version"

Comment: rake is a separate gem its not a part of ruby... it might get installed with rubygems or rvm if you did a normal install but it isn't a part of ruby core.

Comment: How is rake "included with ruby"?

Answer (score 0):

Loading files require extra working memory. Cutting off some features and loading them only when necessary with explicit load command will save memory.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake, but I will post the answer in case anyone else has had the same frustration - the version of Ruby I was using, 1.9.3, has a 9.x version of Rake bundled with the Ruby installation; Capistrano 3 requires a 10.x version. I installed Rake 10.4.2; problem solved.

Note: If you install a 2.1.x or later version of Ruby, you will automatically get a 10.x version of Rake.